# How do I get retrieve data from a form, and then save that as a variable in a java project?

Tags: java, html

I am currently rewriting the website for my FIRST Robotics team, since it was done in GoogleSites and very quickly at that. I have previous knowledge in HTML, CSS, Java, Javascript, and SQL (MySQL and MS SQL). I have a form, and now need to get the data from that form and save it as a variable to upload to my database table.

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input name="username" type="text">
    <br><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input name="password" type="text">

    <input type="submit" name="submit_login" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I also have this in java:

```
String username = "This is a message.";
query("INSERT INTO blog (username, password) VALUES ('" + username + ", '" +
password + "');");
```

The query() method already uploads the query to MySQL and adds it to a table. So back to the question, how do I get the data from the site saved as a variable in my java project? Is it possible without php?

Comment: You should look into the various Java Web frameworks available, such as Spring MVC (my preference, especially with Boot) or Jersey. And read up on SQL injection attacks and password security; you're asking for several different varieties of trouble.

Comment: @chrylis thank you. I have heard of sql injection, and will edit my query to fix that. Right now I am just focused on getting it to work. I will look up on Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are going to `POST` the data to a servlet,

The servlet will have an overriden `doPost` method, where you can perform your DB 
insert.

Follow the [servlet tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html)

Comment: Can servlets be run without any containers like Tomcat? I would suggest a containerless http service, using jetty or similar

Comment: @faizan As per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server) - `Jetty is a Java HTTP (Web) server and Java Servlet container.`